# How to disable smooth scrolling

Tags: 18.04, libinput

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 and smooth scrolling is enabled everywhere. Is there a way to turn it off? From my experience in Debian, switching to libinput causes this exact-to-the-pixel scrolling behavior. Is there a way to get back the old three-line scroll?

Answer (score 0):

Running these two commands in the terminal worked for me:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.mouse natural-scroll false

gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad natural-scroll false
```

I hope it helps, and if this is not what you are looking for, you can roll back the changes by entering:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.mouse natural-scroll true

gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad natural-scroll true
```

Comment: FYI, `natural-scroll` is not smooth scrolling. It's just the "Natural Scrolling" option in the Mouse settings panel.